# Compile XSD to C# objects include namespace

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, xsd, schema

I'm generating objects and class es from XSD files. But the classes created under one namespace and not with the target namespace of the XSD.
How can I compile the schema, and the class should be generated under the namespace?

Here is my code fore example:

```
// generate an assembly representing the given schema:
var codeNamespace = new CodeNamespace(namespaceName);
var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var codeGenerationOptions = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    codeProvider.GenerateCodeFromNamespace(codeNamespace, writer,
                                           codeGenerationOptions);
    code = writer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: How do you generate classes from XSD? Using xsd.exe?

Comment: By "target namespace of the XSD", you do *not* mean the namespace indicated as the target namespace within the XSD file, right? (that namespace is something quite different from .NET namespaces, and its name probably cannot be translated without specifying the actual conversion scheme used)

Comment: In the schema I set the target namespace, and I want that the generated class should have this namespace. How can I do it?

Comment: The targetNamespace in you .xsd file is the namespace of the WSDL schema, which is NOT the same as the namespace of your generated classes and should not be so.  Your XSD namespace needs to be unique worldwide but your code namespace is only unique within your codebase.  If you are using XSD.EXE to generate the classes, you can provide the namespace as a command line parameter.

Comment: I do not use the XSD.EXE, My goal is to have class for each complex type, and in case the XSD import another schema with the same name of complex type, but the namespace is different, to have this class also, but with the XSD namespace. I hope I'm clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example works in that it puts the generated code in the namespace you specify in your `namespaceName` variable.  If you want your namespace to match the XSD, you can set your `namespaceName` variable accordingly.

For example, if I define `string namespaceName = "My.Namespace.One";` in your example code, the resulting value of code is `"namespace My.Namespace.One {\r\n\r\n}"` as expected.

Thus you would simply need to read the namespace from your XSD and assign it to `namespaceName`  If your issue is that you are wanting to use multiple namespaces, then the issue is related to how you process the XSD for code generation, which is not shown at all in your example.

However to actually compile the code you generate, the namespace will need to conform to C# limitations.  A namespace like `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml` would not compile in C#.  That namespace *may* (I'm not sure) be valid at the IL byte code level, but even if it is I would really wonder if what you are doing is worth expending that sort of effort, especially considering it would be a pain for C# to use the generated assembly.

I have the feeling that some details may be missing from your question/example and this may not be the info you are looking for; however, I believe this answer is consistent with what you have provided.